# Unexpected array results in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

This is a difficult issue but I'm not sure where to turn. To sum it up from the start, I'm having trouble with arrays in c++. To head off your inevitable response, I have to use arrays, I can't use vectors. The reason being that I will eventually be interfacing this with CUDA which can't accept vectors.

Anyway, I have written my own class to handle 2D arrays and all the stuff that goes with that behind the scenes. The header file is reproduced at the bottom of this question. I use this class to define a 6 x 10 array. I then loop over many items, primarily using the add method of my class. At some point in this complicated loop, the size of my array switches from 6 x 10 to 0 x 1074266112. I have tried to debug my code and figure out what the issue is but for the life of me I cannot find the issue.

I've printed out all the values at the moment the array size changes, and none of them are out of the norm and I'm never trying to index the array outside of the 6x10 size. In fact, it never even happens at the same point of the loop, it just seems to happen randomly for each run. The only constant I can find between each issue is that the new array size is always exactly 0 x 1074266112.

Sorry I can't provide a minimum working example, but this issue only crops up in my large program and I can't reproduce it in a smaller program. I was at least hoping anyone could see if I'm doing anything wrong with my Matrix program below and possibly suggest a method of debugging.

**EDIT**: If I change this to use a vector rather than an array, the issue goes away. I.e., if I change the relevant parts to `vector<double> data` and upon instantiating, `data = *(vector<double>(x * y))`, the issue mentioned above is no longer a problem. However I have no idea what could be the problem with making this an array.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#ifndef MATRIX_H
#define MATRIX_H

using std::vector; using std::cout; using std::endl;

class Matrix {
    //Define the private variables associated with any instance of this class.
    double * data;      //The 1D pointer which points to the array
    int w, h;           //The width and height of the 2D array that the 1D data array represents
public:

    Matrix(){}
    Matrix(int x, int y){ setSize(x,y); }

    void setSize(int x, int y){ w = x; h = y; data = new double[x * y]; setAll(0); }

    //Two methods to get the height and width of the effective 2D array
    int getWidth(){ return w; }
    int getHeight(){ return h; }

    //Several methods used to set and get the values of elements within the array as well as extracting
    //rows and columns as vectors.
    void set(int x, int y, double value){ data[y*w + x] = value; }
    void setAll(double value);
    double get(int x, int y){ return data[y*w + x]; }
    vector<double> getCol(int x);
    vector<double> getRow(int y);

    //Several methods to adjust the current value by the input
    void increment(int x, int y){ data[y*w + w] += 1; }
    void add(int x, int y, double value){ data[y*w + x] += value; }
    void subtract(int x, int y, double value){ data[y*w + x] -= value; }
    void multiply(int x, int y, double value){ data[y*w + x] *= value; }
    void divide(int x, int y, double value){ data[y*w + x] /= value; }

};

void Matrix::setAll(double value){
    for (int i = 0; i < w*h; i++){
        data[i] = value;
    }
}

vector<double> Matrix::getCol(int x){
    vector<double> column(h);
    for (int i = 0; i < h; i++){ column[i] = data[i*w + x]; }
    return column;
}

vector<double> Matrix::getRow(int y){
    vector<double> row(w);
    for (int i = 0; i < w; i++){ row[i] = data[y*w + i];    }
    return row;
}

#endif  /* MATRIX_H */
```

Comment: You can put the data in a vector, and when you need to pass it to CUDA, just pass `&your_vector[0]` as the "array", and CUDA will be fine with that.

Comment: The only issue with this is that I want to have this class defined for use in CUDA as well, which means it needs access to these methods. I don't want to just pass the arrays, but the object which has the functionality this class provides.

Comment: You have several issues.  First, your class fails to follow the rule of 3 (no user-defined copy constructor / assignment operator / destructor).  Second, calling`setSize` multiple times on the same object causes a memory leak.

Comment: Yes I know, there were components of the class I left out for brevity. The stuff I left in was what I thought were the relevant components.

Comment: @zephyr `Yes I know, there were components of the class I left out for brevity. The stuff I left in was what I thought were the relevant components.`  C++ doesn't work this way.  There are intricacies going on that you may not even be aware of.  If you're creating copies of your Matrix class, or you're calling `setSize` more than once, no one will ever know about the error.  You need to post those very important functions that are missing.  Also post *how* you're using these objects, i.e.are `Matrix` instances being returned or passed by-value?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Currently I don't copy any Matrix objects. They are global variables known to the entire program. I also only ever call setSize upon initialization of the array, never after that. Right now I use pointers to Matrix objects, but I believe in the future I will require passing by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `increment` method is wrong; it depends only on `y` when from context it looks like you intended to also use `x` in the array index calculation. If you're calling this `increment` somewhere in your program, you're probably writing to memory off in la-la land somewhere. I don't know if that's the only cause of your issue, but anyway it will corrupt your heap in probably unhelpful ways.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that issue out. I had not noticed that before now. However, that isn't the issue I'm facing now I don't think. The array that is causing the issue never uses the increment method. It only ever uses the add method.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer for now because it appears to have fixed my problem I believe. Even though I was never calling increment on this particular array, calling increment on another array must've been screwing with this one. Fixing that mistake you found has removed this issue! Thanks so much!